# Parentheses as string in Excel formula

Tags: excel, string, replace, split

1. How can I put ( or ) as argument inside Excel formula ?

`= Replace(A1; "("; 1; "|")` will error out.

2. This comme from another target I want to achieve. I have a column with entries such as `Number(11,0)` or `Text(80)`, I would want to split them into 2 columns : One with type only `(Number; Text)` and the other column with precision `(11,0 ; 80)` . My approach is to first replace ( and ) with a common sign e.g. | . Then I will split using | as delimiter. Any suggestion of a better approach ?

Comment: I believe your order of criteria is wrong: the second and third argument should be numbers.  You probably want SUBSTITUTE: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1;"(";"|")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `REPLACE` is a number, not a string. The correct function may be `SUBSTITUTE`.